# Passing javascript to Rails helper

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I created a simple javascript on getting the URL on my browser under my `application.js` file:

```
function get_url {
 var url = window.location.href;
 return url;
}
```

Then on my `helper/application_helper.rb` file I called the javascript:

```
def get_full_url_helper
 javascript_tag(
     "get_url()\";"
 )
end
```

I tried to pass this on other helper just to see if its getting the full url:

```
def active_url
  get_full_url_helper
  byebug
end
```

Upon using byebug instead of getting the full url on the browser it returns this weird `<script>//<![CDATA[] get_url </script>` thing. For some reason its not calling the right function so I can get the text URL and so something with it.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Anyone here who knows the answer?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the end goal is in this case? Usually it is not advisable to call JS helper methods in Backend (That will have to be done in a hacky way, if at all possible) Maybe we could help out with another way of achieving the end goal?

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal just to get the complete URL that has special character for instance `localhost:3000/#reference` this wont just work with regular orginal_url of request.fullpath

Comment: You should call `get_full_url_helper` in a view and see whether it works or not, it should work when called in a view. `<%= get_full_url_helper %>`. Please try once.

Comment: I did try but did not work out.

Comment: @RichardThompson Have you tried using `request.fullpath` in your controller? I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal: Yes I tried it all even `original_url` but it did not workout for me for special characters like `#`

Comment: Maybe you could try passing the URL as a parameter with the request?

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your `function get_url` be:

```
function get_url() { // <--- parentheses were missing in your sample
 var url = window.location.href;
 return url;
}
```

Also, a simple way to debug what the issue might be (and perhaps find out where your issue might be) is to just modify your `get_full_url_helper` to be:

```
def get_full_url_helper
 javascript_tag(
     "console.log('hello!');"
 )
end
```

and then verify whether it is being invoked on your page in developer console tab in your browser.